# Optimal way to insert records in MySQL master-detail table pair

Tags: mysql, delphi, query-optimization, master-detail

I have a unit in my project that performs message exchange between users. I use two MySQL tables for this purpose:

```
CREATE TABLE `tmessages` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `header` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `body` text,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

that is master. It contains information on sender, header, body of the message etc. and

```
CREATE TABLE `tmessage_recipients` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idmessage` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `idstuff_recipient` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  ...,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`idmessage`,`idstuff_recipient`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

as detail with inforation on users whom the message was sent to, date/time of opening the message etc. (the rest of the information is set by triggers) The following code works properly and the messages are sent.

```
var
  s: string;
  idmessage: longword;
  i: Word;
...    
      s := 'INSERT INTO `tmessages` SET ' + '`header`=' + QuotedStr(Edit12.Text) +
        ', ' + '`body`=' + QuotedStr(Memo3.Text);
      Hdm1.FDConnection1.ExecSQL(s);
      idmessage := Hdm1.FDConnection1.ExecSQLScalar('SELECT `id` FROM `tmessages` '
        + 'WHERE `header`=' + QuotedStr(Edit12.Text) + 'AND `body`=' +
        QuotedStr(Memo3.Text) + ' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1');
      for i := 0 to ListBox3.Count - 1 do
      begin
        s := 'INSERT INTO `tmessage_recipients` SET ' + '`idmessage`=' +
          inttostr(idmessage) + ', ' + '`idstuff_recipient`=' +
          inttostr(ListBox3.ItemByIndex(i).Tag);
        Hdm1.FDConnection1.ExecSQL(s);
      end;
```

But I suppose that it is not optimal as i have to fetch idmessage first. How can I optimize the procedure and make it more reliable? Can insert be done in one call of `Hdm1.FDConnection1.ExecSQL()`?

**Edit**

Using the comments of @Alex Tartan and @whosrdaddy I came to something like this. Is it the optimal way? Or I need to change something?

```
  s:= 'INSERT INTO `tmessages` (`header`,`body`) VALUES(:p1, :p2);'#13#10 +
    'SET @last_id := (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());';
  for i := 0 to ListBox3.Count - 1 do
    s := s + #13#10'INSERT INTO `tmessage_recipients` (`idmessage`,`idstuff_recipient`)'
      + ' VALUES(@last_id,' + inttostr(ListBox3.ItemByIndex(i).Tag) + ');';
  Hdm1.FDConnection1.ExecSQL(s, [Edit12.Text, Memo3.Text]);
```

**Edit 2**

With the proposal of @kobik I came to the following:

```
  s:= 'INSERT INTO `tmessages` (`header`,`body`) VALUES(:p1, :p2);'#13#10 +
    'SET @last_id := (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());';
  for i := 0 to ListBox3.Count - 1 do
    s := s + #13#10'INSERT INTO `tmessage_recipients` (`idmessage`,`idstuff_recipient`)'
      + ' VALUES(@last_id,' + inttostr(ListBox3.ItemByIndex(i).Tag) + ');';

  HDM1.FDQViaFDTransaction.Transaction.StartTransaction;
  try
    HDM1.FDQViaFDTransaction.ExecSQL(s, [Edit12.Text, Memo3.Text]);
    HDM1.FDQViaFDTransaction.Transaction.Commit;
  except
    HDM1.FDQViaFDTransaction.Transaction.Rollback;
  end;
```

**Edit 3**

With the valued advice of @Rick-James the code was transformed to the following...

```
  s := 'INSERT INTO `tmessages` (`header`,`body`) VALUES(:p1, :p2);'#13#10 +
    'SET @last_id := (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());';
  s := s + #13#10'INSERT INTO `tmessage_recipients` ' +
    '(`idmessage`,`idstuff_recipient`)'#13#10'VALUES';
  for i := 0 to ListBox3.Count - 1 do
    s := s + #13#10'(@last_id,' + inttostr(ListBox3.ItemByIndex(i).Tag) + '),';
  s[High(s)] := ';';

  Hdm1.FDQViaFDTransaction.Transaction.StartTransaction;
  try
    Hdm1.FDQViaFDTransaction.ExecSQL(s, [Edit12.Text, Memo3.Text]);
    Hdm1.FDQViaFDTransaction.Transaction.Commit;
    ShowMessage('Message sent.');
    Button10Click(self);
  except
    Hdm1.FDQViaFDTransaction.Transaction.Rollback;
  end;
```

Comment: Please stop using concatenated queries, you are vulnerable to SQL injection. Use parameters instead...

Comment: Better use a transaction

Comment: Thank you, @whosrdaddy, I made an edit. Do you think I need to change something else?

Comment: Thank you, @kobik. Do you mean some mid tier (like `DataSnap`) or calling query from an `FDQuery`?

Comment: You need a single transaction to keep the integrity of your data. look into `TFDTransaction` or use mysql `START TRANSACTION`/`COMMIT`... also, if you have new questions please post a new question.

Comment: Thank you, @kobik for your advice. I am trying not to ask anything except the subject of the current question _"Optimal way to insert records in MySQL master-detail table pair"_. The question is edited using your proposal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a mysql variable:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id,value) VALUES(1,'test');
SET @last_id := (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());
INSERT INTO table2 (id,colName) VALUES(@last_id,"newVal_1");
...
INSERT INTO table2 (id,colName) VALUES(@last_id,"newVal_n");
```

This way you only need one call to the server

Comment: Thank you. I did not know LAST_INSERT_ID() function! Does it return first key field in table or field named `id`?

Comment: Nope. It returns the column that has autoincrement set. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

Comment: Thank you once again. I made an edit of my question including your answer and @whosrdaddy 's comment. Do I need to change something else?

Answer (score 3):

For greater efficiency, use a multi-row INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO table2 
    (id, x)
    VALUES
    (@last_id,"newVal_1"),
    (@last_id,"newVal_2"),
    (@last_id,"newVal_3");
```

Comment: Thank you, Rick James, I have edited my post. Unfortunately I can not accept more than one answer, I can only upwote.

Comment: Thanks.  In some cases, multi-row gives a 10x speedup.